# Parameters considered during hashing files

Tags: cryptography, md5, sha256

I am using MD5 and SHA256 algorithms for calculating hash. I know the procedure to calculate hash. But I do not know what parameters(like content in a file, file size) are considered while hashing a file. I searched on google but I did not find answer. And how can I optimize the process of hashing a file with size greater than 10 GB?

Comment: No _parameters_ are considered. It hashes the file (content) and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Hashing has no parameters, the algorithm takes and input and generates a fixed size output.

You can perform an incremental hash instead of loading the complete file getting chunks and adding each chunk to the calculation. For example (pseudocode)

```
SHA256.init()
SHA256.update(chunk 1)
SHA256.update(chunk 2)
...
SHA256.update(chunk n)
SHA256.digest ()
```